# Socket - sending a big string in c

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to understand why my function dosnt sending the all string (Its send only 53576 elements from 365568: 
This is the function I am using in the client side:

```
#define DATASIZEBUFFER 4000// 365568
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);/* Error handling function */


void TcpClient ( char *servIP , unsigned short echoServPort , Hash_t *HashData)//(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sock;                           //Socket descriptor 
struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;    //Echo server address            
int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;      //Bytes read in single recv()
                                    //and total bytes read      

// Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP 
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    DieWithError(" socket () failed") ;

// Construct the server address structure 
memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));  /* Zero out structure */
ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;               /* Internet address family */
ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);/* Server IP address */
ServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);    /* Server port */

// Establish the connection to the server 
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError(" connect () failed") ;
for (;;)
{
// Send the string to the server //

    if (send(sock, HashData->array , HashData->elementNumber, 0) != HashData->elementNumber)
    {
        printf ("Bytes Nedded to recived: %ld\nAnd (DATASIZEBUFFER) is %d\n", HashData->elementNumber , DATASIZEBUFFER);
        DieWithError("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a library that supports a user level buffer. I wrote [my own library for this](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools/blob/master/docs/libsock.md) and I'm happy to share.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`send()` does not guarantee that it would send **all** the data.

From send man page:

> ```
>    On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error,
>    -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
> ```

You can write a loop around `send()` and invoke it multiple times until all data is sent (or, error is returned). It could be something like the following (please modify it based on your needs):

```
size_t 
Send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flag) {
  size_t sent_total = 0;
  for (int sent_now = 0; sent_total != len; sent_total += sent_now) {
    sent_now = send(sockfd, buf + sent_total, len - sent_total, flag);
    if (sent_now == -1) break;
  }
  if (sent_total != len) {
    LOG("send requested = %zu, sent = %zu", len, sent_total);
  }
  return sent_total;
}
```

---

Update to address @Myst's comments:

Although the question did not mention it explicitly, I assumed that the sockets used are **blocking**, since there are no `fcntl` call. With that in mind, the following from send() man page explains the situation:

> ```
>    When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
>    send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
>    nonblocking I/O mode. 
>
>    In nonblocking mode it would fail with the
>    error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in this case.  The select(2) call may be
>    used to determine when it is possible to send more data.
> ```

For non-blocking socket, the design need to be different and is outside the scope of this discussion.

Comment: You should probably add poking to the loop (such as `select`), or you'll be burning CPU cycles for nothing.

Comment: @Myst send() suspend an execution until it receive some data (or an error occurs), so I don't understand your point.

Comment: @DavideVisentin... `write` suspends execution. `send` will return immediately with the value `-1` and errno will be set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`...

Comment: @Myst you're right. Anyhow in the code above idf send return -1 it exit from the loop.

Comment: @DavideVisentin, this is why the code in your answer doesn't work. You will exit from the loop before the data is sent. Either implement polling or loop until `-1` is returned AND the `errno` is neither `EAGAIN` nor `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: @Myst I have updated the answer in response to your discussion.

Comment: @Arun  nice update - but I can't upvote your answer more then once... Nice answer :)

Comment: @Myst  you said that  "write suspends execution" Whare did you saw it?

Comment: The code is not working :-(
additionally what is LOG function?

Comment: @YosefAlon: What is the problem you are facing? As noted in the answer, **please modify it based on your needs**. Logging is optional; for ease of troubleshooting and understanding code behavior, a common strategy is to **log** unusual events, you can use your own logging function, or **printf** if there is none.

Comment: @Myst, Thanks now its working.
the problem was inside a loop and if condition problems. 
your function helped me, thanks.